# Unable to deploy in house iOS app via Profile Manager to one specific iPad

Tags: ios, ipad, profile-manager, enterprise

We have an in house iPad app that we have setup for distribution with the provisioning profile from our iOS Enterprise Developer account.

Before properly signing the app with the enterprise provisioning profile (it was signed ad-hoc) I uploaded the app to Profile Manager and attempted to push it to a device that was not configured for that ad-hoc profile. When I attempted to push it the iPad displayed a message that the server wanted to install the app, it then downloaded it and gave a message that this iPad could not run this app.

I removed that ad-hoc version from Profile Manager and properly signed it with the enterprise provisioning profile. I transferred the ipa via iTunes and it installed and ran fine.
I deleted the app and the provisioning profile from the iPad and uploaded the new properly signed IPA file to Profile Manager and attempted to push it to this same iPad. Profile Manager shows that it is sent but the iPad never prompts to install.

I was able to push it to another iPad enrolled in Profile Manager with no problems, but nothing I do will prompt the other iPad to install the app.

Any thoughts on what could be going on?

Answer (score 1):

See page 5 of the iOS_Security_Oct12.pdf document. iOS won't allow an in-house app to run on a device that doesn't have the corresponding provisioning profile - this ensures that the app cannot be run on an unauthorized device.

http://images.apple.com/iphone/business/docs/iOS_Security_Oct12.pdf

Answer (score 0):

I had this once before, the app would not install on a particular device, and it turned out that the device had been jailbroken. When the device was restored, the app installed fine.